# Highchart Scatter plot with 2 series, tooltip refresh command giving error

Tags: highcharts

I have 1 chart with 2 scatterplot series like so 
[image]

The series have same data points, basically I am drawing 2-2D plots instead of 1-3D plot..

Series 1 has the legend while on 2 its disabled. When I hover my cursor over the legend I want the tooltip to show up in both the chart, so a user can correlate legend to points on scatter plots.

```
$('.highcharts-legend text, .highcharts-legend span').each(function (index, element) {
    $(element).hover(function () {
        chart.tooltip.refresh([chart.series[index].data[0], chart.series[index+data.length].data[0]]);
    }, function () {
        chart.tooltip.hide();
    })
});
```

I use above code to create desired effect, but tooltip is not appearing at the right place. maybe its a limitation from highchart. It throws the following JS error 
[image]

Could someone please suggest me a workaround?

If you could make the chart.tooltip.refresh to function properly that would be the best. Other wise I am willing to make a compromise with at-least having the points in both series in hovered state and 1 of them showing the tooltip.

here is a fiddle to see the problem in action https://jsfiddle.net/9eoyg283/1/ , Hover over the legend items and you would get JS error in the console.

I can create the desired effect if I create 2 charts instead of using 2 series, but then that complicates other things which are not desirable. So this solution is off

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @user4772933, Please check the result with enabled `shared` property: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g7erkhow/

Comment: That is of no use in this case. For 1) the tooltip appears at a random place, not near to the either points when the graph is densely populated 2) i still don't get to know where the point is in the second series. Point doesn't get hovered state or something. i have played with this setting already, its not what I desire.

Comment: You can wrap `getAnchor` method and set hover state on series. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1zj0ny3o/